# holomorphic function and simply connected region

Tags: complex-analysis

I knew that if $f$ is holomorphic on region $A$ which is simply connected and $f$ has no zero in $A$, then there exists $g$ s.t. $g$ is holomorphic on $A$ and $f$ is the $n$th power of $g$ for some $n$.

Is there any algebraic interpretation or algebraic geometrical intepretation?

All unit in the $H(A)$ where $H(A)$ means holomorphic functions on $A$ is the form of power..but i don't know the essential meaning

Comment: Hint: Is it possible to choose a branch of logarithm that contains the image of $f$?

Comment: braindead I know how to prove but I want to know algebraic or geometrical intepretation

Answer (score 1):

A simple consequence of this is that the group of units of $H(A)$ is a divisible abelian group.

Comment: Is there any relation with algebraic geometry?

Comment: Actually nothing else but this comes to my mind...

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Consider the map $f \colon A \to \mathbb{C} \backslash\{0\}$ and the [covering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space) $\, p\colon \mathbb{C} \backslash\{0\} \to \mathbb{C} \backslash\{0\}$, $\,z \mapsto z^n$. Since $A$ is simply connected and $f$ is continuous, there exists a [lift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space#Lifting_properties) of $f$ --    a continuous map $\, g \colon A \to \mathbb{C} \backslash\{0\}$ such that $p \circ g = f$, that is $g^n = f$. Since $f$ is moreover holomorphic, and $p$ is locally invertible, it follows that $g$ is also holomorphic.

Comment: thank you but i knew the proof but i want to know algebraic or geometrical interpretation

Comment: Ah, sorry, you are right. There is something involving cohomology of sheaves. It turns out that for any open subset $A$ of $\mathbb{C}$ we have $G/ nG \simeq H^1(A, \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$, where $G$ is the group of holomorphic functions with no zeroes.